# No output from pdftk

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I am trying to add a background to a PDF with pdftk:

```
$ pdftk ./sources/Skills.pdf background ./Background.pdf output test.pdf verbose
Command Line Data is valid.

Input PDF Filenames & Passwords in Order
( <filename>[, <password>] ) 
   ./sources/Skills.pdf

The operation to be performed: 
   filter - Apply 'filters' to a single, input PDF based on output args.
      (When the operation is omitted, this is the default.)

The output file will be named:
   test.pdf

Output PDF encryption settings:
   Output PDF will not be encrypted.

No compression or uncompression being performed on output.

Creating Output ...
```

The process is then stuck. It created the output file but without any content.

```
$ ls -l  test.pdf 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 corti  macports  0 Aug  9 14:27 test.pdf
```

I am using pdftk 2.02

> pdftk 2.02 a Handy Tool for Manipulating PDF Documents Copyright (c)
>   2003-13 Steward and Lee, LLC - Please Visit: www.pdftk.com This is
>   free software; see the source code for copying conditions. There is NO
>   warranty, not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
>   PURPOSE.

Any idea what could be the problem? Are there other (free) alternatives to add a PDF as a background for a second PDF?

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue after upgrading to OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

The solution Sid Stewart, the creator of pdftk, offered up to a different stack exchange question did the trick for me.

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32505951

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248310

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you are adding any value with a '/', just remove or replace. I had the same issues and now it is working back!